# Presentation with embedded video: from LibreOffice Impress to MS PowerPoint

Tags: powerpoint, libreoffice

I am a linux user, and I need to prepare a presentation that must be load on a Windows Computer with MS Office.
I work with LibreOffice and in the conversion everything goes fine creating a jpg image for every slide (I don't need special effects or editable texts). The problem occurs when I try to embed a video in my presentation, bacause PowerPoint can't load them. I tried with .avi and .mp4 videos and both .ppt and .odp presentation file formats. 
Is there a way to prepare a presentation with embedded videos that works in both softwares?

thanks
Alessandro

Comment: This seems like a question for SuperUser rather than StackOverflow (which is for questions about programming)

Comment: Thanks Steve I'll try asking on SuperUser to ;-)

Comment: Actually, I've found a solution... saving in .ppt format and keeping the video file in the same directory, because it seems that .ppt doesn't embed the video in the presentation's file, but it create only a link to the file's path...

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I've found a solution... saving in .ppt format and keeping the video file in the same directory, because it seems that Microsoft's .ppt doesn't embed the video in the presentation's file, but it create only a link to the file's path...

Answer (score 0):

My son made a presentation in Libre Office Impress under Linux. But in school they only have Microsoft PowerPoint under Windows. So he had to convert it to PowerPoint.

The conversion works quite well if you take care of a few obstacles:

- Don't use embedded videos. Instead put them in the same directory as the Impress presentation and insert the video as a link. Then it works fine after conversion.
- Because the videos are not embedded you should use more common video formats, like `.mp4`. For example one video in the format `.webm` works on my linux machine, but it doesn't work on a windows PC. Maybe because some codecs are not installed.
- Linked Videos are starting in Libre Office Impress by themselves. After converting to PowerPoint they only start after clicking on them. You have to change this behavior after conversion inside PowerPoint manually (what is not so nice if you have many of them...)
- Don't save the `.odt` file in the new PowerPoint format `.pptx` because then pictures are not scaled correctly. Instead save it in the old PowerPoint format `.ppt`
  Even online converter like [zamzar.com](https://www.zamzar.com/) use the old `.ppt` format.
- If you are still not satisfied with the result then you have the possibility to create a video of the Impress presentation instead of showing it with PowerPoint. This would be a realistic plan B with all effects ;-)